# Is there a better way to reference the final child class (which can vary) in a series of extended classes?

Tags: php, oop, extends

In the application I am currently developing, there is one crucial function which calls one of many possible public static methods:

```
$methodID = // carve up user's input to arrive at this

$importantValue = {{className}}::$methodID($arg); // {{ }} are to emphasize this is not the finished line of code....see below
```

However, the problem I am encountering is that **className** can vary depending on the user input. The base class is **A**, but **className** is either **A** or **B** depending on the user input:

```
class A {
    // all the base methods
}

class B extends A {
    // certain user inputs necessitate these additional methods
}
```

My (perhaps a hack) solution right now is to initiate, then edit the value of, a public static variable to change the identity of {{className}} above as necessary:

```
publicValues::$myClass = $conditions_for_class_B_exist ? 'B' : 'A';
```

so that the finished line of code is:

```
$className = publicValues::$myClass;

$importantValue = $className::$methodID($arg);
```

There must be a better way, especially since future updates will likely require extending to a third class, i.e., **C**.

*Is there an object-oriented solution to referencing a variably-extended class?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that late static bindings, using the keyword `static` are the solution you're looking for.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

```
<?php
class A {
    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
    public static function test() {
        static::who(); // Here comes Late Static Bindings
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
}

B::test(); // Outputs "B"
?>
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm going to try this out...will def upvote if it works for me

Comment: yes...this worked. I have encountered an additional issue now but your answer works ---> upvoted

Comment: If an answer solves your problem, please mark it as accepted so that future readers know it is a solution to the problem you described.

Comment: Yes, but waiting a bit to see if any other answers appear